# Custom pocket pc 2005-08 application deployment issue

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6, smart-device

I have developed one custom pocket pc application for Motorola MC-2100 device. I need to read the barcode and display it on textbox on my Windows CE device.
When i run this app on emulator it works fine, but when i deploy it on my Windows CE device it throghs below error :-

```
File or assembly name 'Symbol.Barcode, Version=1.5.1.1, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=68EC8DB391F150CA', or one of its dependencies, was not found.
```

I already installed .net compact framework on device. Can any one help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: install the symbol assembly with your app.?

Comment: Symbol assemblies are already there in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and Install [EMDK for .NET v2.8.](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Search?searchType=simple&searchTerm=emdk%20download%20https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Search?searchType=simple&searchTerm=emdk%20download)

and use `Symbol.Barcode2.dll`. Sample code is also there.This will help you.